# Monit wont start/stop any processes

Tags: linux, monit

I've got monit running on a linux vserver, installed in a custom location

```
/home/user/bin/monit
```

as that is the only suitable location according to the webhost providers. When I installed  monit I used ./configure --prefix=/home/user

Monit itself runs, and sends me emails of it's activity, and the control file syntax is correct. However, monit cannot seem to start or stop anything - or even run the simplest of scripts. eg. Using 'monit stop all', I try to run the following stop command

```
stop = "/bin/bash /home/user/simple_script.sh"
```

Which fails (and says so in the log). I cant figure out why this is failing, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

We use monit talso, and we have something like that in our scripts:

```
check process cron with pidfile /var/run/crond.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/cron start"
    stop  program = "/etc/init.d/cron stop"
    group system
    depends cron_init, cron_bin

check file cron_init with path /etc/init.d/cron
    group system

check file cron_bin with path /usr/sbin/cron
    group system
```

Can you show us monit logs?

Answer (score 2):

Is monit running as root? If it isn't, it may not have the appropriate permissions to make these changes. Quick and dirty way to check is `ps aux | grep monit`

Answer (score 1):

Is simple_script.sh what monit is also starting?  The stop needs to be an actual command that is used to stop the command from running, not just the name of the script itself.

Comment: I figured that the monit start/stop directives will try and run any command, so have just created simple_script which write a date into a file (which i can check to see if its run).. In a way I'm trying to isolate the problem, as I figure if it can reach that file and run it, then I can work up from that.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something though?

Comment: In this case, the stop command needs to be what command specifically monit needs to issue to stop the process from running.

Comment: I appreciate your help, however the problem is that I cannot run *anything* I put in the start/stop directives - everything I've tried gives me a 'failed to start' message. The actual command I want to run is "/usr/bin/ruby /home/user/site/script/backgroundrb stop", but for now I'd be happy with a 'hello world'